# How do I uncompress a tarball that uses .xz?

Tags: tar, compression

I'm used to extracting tarballs with a `-xfz` flag, which handles gzip and bzip2 archives.

Recently I've run into a `.tar.xz` file and I would like to uncompress it in one step using `tar`, how can I do that?

Comment: note you may have to install `xz-utils` if not already present

Comment: here's my little script that guesses tar flags for you: https://gist.github.com/shime/5908634

Comment: `tar --help` lists `tar` flags. 
`-xzf` applies to `gzip`. 
`-xjf` to `bz2`. 
`-xJf` to `xz`.

Comment: Better Question to ask than how to do this with tar: Use `unar` or `7z` and never worry about choosing the right program for your type of archive again. This is the only feasible solution looking forward with more and more archive types coming. Unless you care about the technical details...

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/unp/

Answer (score 1240, accepted):

Ubuntu includes GNU tar, which recognizes the format by itself! One command works with any supported compression method, per [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC131).

```bash
# The same command handles any compression format! Ex:

tar xf archive.tar.xz  # for .tar.xz files
tar xf archive.tar.gz  # for .tar.gz files
tar xf archive.tar     # for .tar files
```

etc. If tar gives a `Cannot exec` error, you may need to `sudo apt install xz-utils` first.

Comment: I think that's with bsdtar :)

Comment: It's a feature of GNU tar. I don't know about competing implementations, but GNU tar should be the most relevant to ubuntu.  http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC131

Comment: if you run into `tar: xz: Cannot exec: No such file or directory`, install `xz-utils`: `sudo apt-get install xz-utils`

Comment: If you cant remember that, it stands for, and is the same as: `tar --extract --file archive.tar.xx`

Comment: This is not an answer, it is a 'you don't care about the answer, even though you asked' response. Spare a thought for people who are not on 'latest'

Comment: What version of `tar` no longer requires the specific flag?

Comment: @SeanHoulihane, it is not an answer because the OP asked a minor [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). ramslök gave the OP better than was asked for, and that included an effective "You don't care about the answer, even though you asked", which was appropriate because it was true.

Comment: I had to use "-" in front of the "xf"

Comment: o tar how i love thee - tape archive - it literally means tape archive and we are STILL using it, fantastic piece of code

Comment: @MarkTomlin and others who ask, compressed archive autodetection was added in GNU tar 1.15, released December 2004.

Comment: @fkraiem You're a necro-answering super star.

Comment: @MarkTomlin I just saw this because it was bumped due to someone (not me) answering. ;)

Comment: This answer didn't work for me, got a `tar: This does not look like a tar archive` error.  Mathias Bynens answer, however, did work.

Comment: Any way to show a progress bar?

Answer (score 398):

Try

`tar -xJf file.pkg.tar.xz`

The `-J` is the flag that specifically deals with .xz files.

Comment: I wonder how many flags will we have in 2020. Like... 45 different compressions? Knowing tar switches is already a black-belt in Linux-fu. :/

Comment: @Shiki: That's probably why it doesn't make you specify the compression format flag anymore. (See ramslök's answer.)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1168/

Comment: This should totally be the accepted answer since it answers the question for any version of tar supporting `.xz`

Comment: @pospi true (I got here looking for the BSD answer for OS X), but this *is* the Ubuntu SE so it makes some sense to assume GNU.

Comment: In the year 2030 flags become Turing complete... 2040 they become sentient

Comment: Even if you change the xz extension to gz, it'll still work. This saved me from recompressing it to match to pre-existing code.

Comment: 2020 here, looks like GNU tar supports 8 compression flags

Answer (score 95):

If for some reason the `tar` solutions don’t work (perhaps because you’re using the OS X built-ins), try this:

```
unxz < file.tar.xz > file.tar
```

…which is equivalent to:

```
xz -dc < file.tar.xz > file.tar
```

Then use `tar` to untar the file.

Comment: That should be constructable with a pipe.

Comment: I feel like you could just do `unxz < file.tar.xz | tar x` or similar.

Comment: this worked for me, where `tar xf` did not. ubuntu 12.04

Comment: At least on my Ubuntu machine, `unxz` is not equivalent to `xz -dc`, but to `xz -d`. So to extract `file.tar.xz` to `file.tar`, you'd simply write `unxz file.tar.xz`. If you want an equivalent to `xz -dc`, decompressing to stdout, use `xzcat`. For example `xzcat file.tar.xz | tar x`.

Answer (score 43):

xz is a lossless data compressor. You will have to extract the tar ball from xz and then extract the tar:

```
unxz my_archive.tar.xz      # results in my_archive.tar
```

Then you know to extract a tar

```
tar -xf my_archive.tar
```

Source: [XZ Utils - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XZ_Utils).

Comment: Best answer. `xz` doesn't need stdout redirection. Even better: `unxz -k`

Comment: @MarkJeronimus I don’t find this so good since it creates an intermediate file. Using [GNU tar](https://askubuntu.com/a/107976/250300) or a [pipe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92328/how-do-i-uncompress-a-tarball-that-uses-xz#comment618114_407911) should demand less resources.

Comment: This worked for me, but it should be noted that it will delete the original tar.xz file

Comment: Yes, this is a straight way to do. 1000 up votes.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem, the `tar xf` command was not able to extract it.
To fix this, you need to install the `xz-utils` package.
The solution was:

```
sudo apt-get install xz-utils
```

then:

```
tar xf myfile.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 20):

```
tar -xvf package.tar.xz
```

`-x` - extract files

`-v` - verbosely list files processed

`-f` - use specified archive file

Answer (score 6):

Just want to add that if you have an old version of [GNU tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/) prior to version 1.22 when the --xz and -J options became available, you could compress or decompress tar.xz files by using `--use-compress-program xz`. For example,

```
tar --use-compress-program xz -cf example.tar.xz file1 file2 file3
```

or

```
tar --use-compress-program xz -xf example.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 5):

If tar recognizes the compression format, you don't need a flag:

`tar xvf *.tar.xz`

If you need to decompress the input manually, for example because your tar is too old to recognize xz, or you need a special path:

`xz -cd  *.tar.xz | tar xvf -`

Pipes are faster than making an uncompressed intermediate file, and use less disk space too!

Answer (score 5):

I like [dtrx](https://brettcsmith.org/2007/dtrx/)

```
sudo apt install dtrx
dtrx your-file.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 4):

Wow, that's a really good one. Was it done with 7zip on a Mac? Try this:

```
7z x -so file.tar.xz | tar xf -
```

Comment: Requires 7z, which isn't what he wants - he wants to do it entirely in tar.

Comment: Yes, thanks - the "xz" got me! Well, it's one step anyway :) And `tar J` = `tar xz`, so we might even write `tar xzf file.tar.xz` like "normal" `tar xvfz file.tar.gz`. So basically no difference. No dash needed before using the switch.

Comment: It's almost like the answer was given in the question. :)

Comment: I was thrown off too because tar zxf errored out on the .xz file, I suppose just using J all the time would be the way to go.

Comment: Yup! The manual page is not in sync with the source: buffer.c uses -J for lzma.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu comes with Python (Python 2.7 and Python 3), which contains the necessary modules for extracting archives. So if for whatever reason `tar` command is missing (say your sysadmin has removed it and you don't have `sudo` privillege to install it), one can use:

```
python3 -c 'import tarfile,sys; b = tarfile.open(sys.argv[1]);print(b.extractall())' ./archive.xz
```

As a short script,that's more readable as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tarfile,sys

with tarfile.open( sys.argv[1] ) as fd:
    fd.extractall()
```

Suppose I created an `.xz` file with `tar cJf thing.xz /etc/passwd`. The archive will contain `etc` directory with `passwd` file inside. Using the above script will result in `etc` directory created in your current working directory, and within it will be `passwd` file. Of course, this can always be extended by specifying path where you want to extract inside the `extractall()` function.

Comment: The [`tarfile` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractall) warns that filenames with an absolute path will extract to the specified directory, not relative to your current working directory as claimed in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`unar`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-unar/) is quite a  nice simple program and easy to type, to unarchive almost any format including 7z and RAR

it seems to be written in (GNU) Objective-C and so requires installation of some `gnustep` (GNU's Objective-C implementation) libraries ([`gnustep-base-runtime`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnustep-base-runtime&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and  [`libgnustep-base1.25`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgnustep-base1.25&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all))

if you use --install-suggests or have configured `apt` to install suggested packages, `unar` will suggest and install many GUI GNUStep programs which are not what you want

```
sudo apt install --no-install-suggests unar 
unar linux-source.tar.xz
```

it will create the output directory `linux-source` automatically.

Comment: Best answer (though the question specifically mentions using tar for the job...). Since installing this I never have to look up how to unpack archive X again. All that knowledge is encoded in that program. This is exactly how everything should *just work together*...