# What is the difference between .tar files

Tags: tar

What is the difference between `.tar.gz` and `.tar.xz` (is there more?)? I know that you can just open up Archive Manager and extract them. But what is the actual difference? Which should I use? What flags should I give `tar` to extract them in CLI?

### EDIT:

What is the difference between the `xz` algorithim and the `gz` algorithim?

Comment: How the algorithms work is a *huge* question, more suited to [compsci](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.tar` (standing for Tape ARchive) files are  the ones created by the `tar` utility. It is capable of putting several files in one single package, but it can't compress them. That's where the `.gz`, `.xz` and `.bz2` extensions enter. The gz format provides the best speed but a "regular" compression ratio. The bz2 format provides a mid-term between speed and compression, while xz is excellent when talking about compression but a little slower.

The big difference between .tar.gz/bz2/xz files and .zip/.7z/.rar files is that the "tar" ones pass through two processes to reach their final forms while the others do it in a single step.

Answer (score 1):

Tar allows you to pack multiple files into a single file, while the other extensions (gz, bz2, xz, lzma, etc.) are the compression types. Specific to your question, .gz compression is the fastest and largest, while .xz is much slower and more effecient.

According to [this question from 3 years ago,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92328/how-do-i-uncompress-a-tarball-that-uses-xz) `tar` can recognize and extract the files without any special flags.

Comment: I would recommend using `tar xzvf file.tar.xx`, as you can see what is going on.

Comment: I edited my post. How does `xz` differ from `gz`?

Comment: Gzip uses the deflate algorithm: http://www.infinitepartitions.com/art001.html Not sure about XZ