# How to open xz file into movie player program

Tags: files, file-format

my friend sent me film with xz format and that file can't open. How to open that xz file in movie player program?

Comment: Sounds like a compressed file, check this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/92328/how-do-i-uncompress-a-tarball-that-uses-xz

Comment: `xz` is a compression format. You uncompress it and then play it.

Comment: Right-click on the file and select extract here.

Comment: Just a reminder: players like VLC have archive reader extensions that can play certain certain types of (compressed) archives as if they were folders. This doesn't work with every compression algorithm though. On the other side the are formats like Matroska with a pleathora of features (ordered chapters, header compression and stripping, font and cover attachments etc.).

Answer (score 2):

xz is a compression file format. To uncompress it

If your file format is tar.xz use

```
tar xf archive.tar.xz
```

and if your file format is xz use

```
unxz archive.xz
```

If you are having problem with **tar xf** command then you may need to install **xz-utils** .
FYI **xz-utils** comes pre-installed in Ubuntu.

To install xz-utils use

```
sudo apt-get install xz-utils
```

You can also use Nautilus to extract the files.
After that use a video player to play your video.

Comment: There is no need to install xz-utils - it is already included in Ubuntu ! :)

Comment: And I doubt you want to use `tar` if you don't have `tar.xz` file. Just `unxz` in that case.

Comment: tar can uncompress tar.xz and xz as well.

Comment: @ThorOdinson No, it doesn't.

Comment: @muru  Answer Updated , Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to extract the `.xz` file. Open the `nautilus` file manager, right-click the file and select Extract Here. Now click on the extracted file and in case it has a format for which all the necessary media plugins are installed, your default media player will open and start playing.