# How do I use an .img.xz file or get an .img file from it?

Tags: server, system-installation, raspberrypi, compression, disk-image

I have a file with an `xz` extension, `ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz`. How do you get the `.img` out of it?

My goal is to flash the file on an SD card. I want to use www.etcher.io I finally got it to work, but etcher will only handle `.iso` and `.img` files.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/q/92328/249734 , but any number of  "decompress and pipe through dd" references will cover well enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far I can see on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system - the GNOME Disks utility allow to restore disk image in GUI way:

1. Select target drive.
2. Click on hamburger button, and then select *Restore Disk Image*

   > [image: GNOME Disks]
3. Then it will ask the path of image file:

   > [image: Select Disk Image to restore]

   here you can select any of **.img*, ***.img.xz** (sic!) and **.iso* formats.
4. Double check that destination is correct and then hit *Start Restoring...* button on opened window.

Comment: Why the `sic`? Is this because `.img.xz` is really a *compressed* disk image and not a "disk image"? In reality it looks like you don't know that `.xz` is a thing and you are pointing out that `.gz` is written typographically wrong...

Answer (score 44):

xz is a compression format like zip or gz. To be able to decompress it from the command line you need to install xz-utils:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xz-utils
```

and then use this command to decompress your file:

```
$ unxz ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz
```

If you are under windows you can use [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org)

Comment: Are there currently supported Ubuntu releases on which xz-utils is not installed by default?

Comment: you can use 7zip in linux as well.

Comment: If you want to keep the compressed file use the option `-k`

Comment: @EliahKagan it seems to me that xz-utils is not pre-installed on Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 17):

#### Decompressing `.xz` files in general

`ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz` is the result of compressing a single file, `ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img`, with `xz`. You can uncompress it with:

```bash
unxz ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz
```

That will extract `ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img` and, assuming it succeeds, delete `ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz`. If you want to keep that original `.xz` file, you can pass the `-k`/`--keep` option:

```bash
unxz -k ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz
```

Note that this is different from what you would *usually* do for a `.tar.xz` file, since `tar` supports decompressing and extraction through a single command. In the case of a `.xz` file (unless the file is very misleadingly named), only decompression is needed.

#### Flashing the preinstalled Ubuntu Server image in particular

The particular file you've downloaded is a preinstalled image for Ubuntu Server 19.10. Assuming the file was correctly and successfully downloaded (see below), you can use [**the official instructions**](https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/installation-media) to flash this image to a storage device. The best way to do this differs depending on what operating system you're using to do it. But assuming it's Ubuntu, here's a summary:

- Find the name of the device that you are writing it to. One way to do this is in Disks (your file browser). **Make sure this is not the name of a device that contains *any* data you wish to keep!**
- Run this command, replacing *`device`* with the device name you found:

  ```bash
  xzcat ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz | sudo dd of=device bs=32M
  ```

  There, `xzcat` is doing the work of `unxz`. If you have a corrupted file, `xzcat` will fail, just as `unxz` would.

  If you ran `unxz` and got a `.img` file, then don't use that command above with `xzcat`. In that case, use this command instead:

  ```bash
  sudo dd if=ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz of=device bs=32M
  ```

It is not typically possible to write a flash drive with `dd` in a WSL system. So if you're running Ubuntu in Windows 10 with WSL, those instructions don't apply. But in that case you can just use a Windows method (see the official instructions).

#### Dealing with possibly incomplete or corrupted files

If decompression fails with an error message about how the file format is not recognized, then especially if running `file` on it is unable to identify the format as `XZ compressed data` (though sometimes otherwise), you likely have a corrupted or incomplete download. You can use `ls -l` to find the length of your file in bytes and compare that length to the expected length--for that particular file, the length should be 661217868. That addresses most cases of incomplete downloads and a few cases of corrupted downloads, but it is far from perfect.

Many files available for downloading, including `ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz` all the Ubuntu images, have checksums that can be used to more reliably gauge if the file was completely and *correctly* downloaded. For security purposes, it's a good idea to check the GPG signautre on the file providing the checksums (and to avoid MD5 checksums, which are weak against deliberate attacks). But for checking for *inadvertent* corruption, it's enough to look up the checksum and test your file.

The kind of checksum provided and recommended for checking Ubuntu images these days is a SHA256SUM. [This file](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/19.10/release/SHA256SUMS) contains the SHA256SUMs for the 19.10 server images, including `ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz`. One of its lines is:

```bash
52ca28f21685eef965d476a716a7bc01237456d6a8770a56630299036eade0bf *ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz
```

Running the `sha256sum` utility on your file should produce a checksum that matches exactly, like this:

```bash
$ sha256sum ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz
52ca28f21685eef965d476a716a7bc01237456d6a8770a56630299036eade0bf  ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz
```

If it does not, then your download was corrupted or incomplete and that's probably the explanation for your difficulty decompressing or otherwise using the file.

Comment: It says the file format is not recognized when I do this.

Comment: @BJsgoodlife What's the exact command you're running and the exact error message you get? Also, what's the output of `ls -l ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz` and `file ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz`? (One way to provide this information could be to edit your question to include it.)

Comment: @Eliiah Kagan unxz ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz
unxz: ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz: File format not recognized. I will edit my question too.

Comment: @BJsgoodlife Thanks. I've expanded my answer to cover what to do when you get this sort of error. Basically, you should check the SHA256SUM to ensure you have a complete and correct download. (I still recommend that you edit your question as planned.) I've also expanded my answer to link to the recommended method of flashing a preinstalled Ubuntu Server image to a storage device, since that's your actual goal here, and I've summarized one of the recommended methods for doing so. Note that this will still only work (and have the desired effect) if you downloaded a complete and uncorrupted file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mkusb-dus` to extract and clone directly from an `img.xz` file (compressed file with `xz`).

- Install [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

  If you run standard Ubuntu live, you need an extra instruction to get the repository Universe. (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu have the repository Universe activated automatically).

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
  ```
- Run `dus` in the directory where you have the file, in general

  ```
  dus file.img.xz
  ```

  in your case

  ```
  dus ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz
  ```

---

It is important that the target drive (the memory card of a Raspberry Pi) is big enough for the image. It must be *exactly* the same size or bigger.

- If there is an MSDOS partition table it will be straightforward to clone an image to a drive that is bigger than the image.
- If there is a GUID partition table, GPT, and the drive is bigger than the image, a backup partition table must be written to the end of the drive. mkusb will do it automatically. With some other cloning tools you may have to fix it yourself afterwards, for example with `gdisk`.

Comment: @sudodus- when I did this, I saw a gui not a Terminal. Where do you type the code?

Comment: @BJsgoodlife, You can open a terminal window and type the code. (It is also possible to do it via a graphical user interface, but I think it is easier to do it directly from a terminal window.)

Answer (score 2):

Open the file with the Archive Manager and extract the `img` file from there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) (Windows, macOS, & Linux) to directly flash the .img.xz image to the SD card. In one step, Etcher will decompress the .img.xz image and flash the resulting .img file to the SD card.

Etcher supports following formats: zip, etch, gz, bz2, xz, img, iso, dsk, hddimg, and raw.