# How to decompress .img.gz a compressed disk image to .img?

Tags: disk-image, compression

Probably this is duplicate, i can't find out related from search engine. How i can extract `.img.gz` file into `.img` file?

i have files archived as .img.xz and .img.gz. i can extract .img.xz using `xz-utils` or `unxz` from [this way](https://askubuntu.com/q/1193232/856659) but i can't locate where is `ungz` to get my miner.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called `gunzip`:

```
gunzip /path/to/my.img.gz
```

This is the same like `gzip -d`