How to make FileZilla work in Ubuntu 24.04?
The filezilla app in the official repositories crashes in Ubuntu 24.04. As a remedy I have downloaded this:
/home/myname/Downloads/FileZilla_3.67.0_x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.xz
I don't have a package to extract this.
I looked for packages here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xz&searchon=names&suite=noble&section=all
I am confused by the descriptions of the packages. How do I decide which one to install?
Thanks to those who have commented, but my question is really simple - how do I choose which package to extract my file? Thanks.

Sounds like you want to simply extract a tar.xz file. Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/a/107976/1684306

Turns out that Filezilla in the official repositories of 24.04 is broken. There are multiple ways to fix the issue.

Use the unofficial Filezilla PPA, which provides the latest version, and manages automatic updates (and automatically adds it to the menu).

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xtradeb/apps
sudo apt update
sudo apt install filezilla


Download the binary from their website and run it manually.

After downloading, extract the tarball. Either right click on it and use the Archive manager program bundled with Ubuntu, or run tar xf $HOME/Downloads/FileZilla_3.67.0_x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.xz
After extracting the tarball, open the extracted folder (FileZilla3), and run the binary executable found in FileZilla3/bin/filezilla.
You can create a desktop file to add it to the menu.
